# Properties of resolvent operators

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I am asked to prove the identities of $(12)$ and $(13)$, which are given on page 438 of the textbook PDE Evans, 2nd edition as follows:

> **THEOREM 3** (Properties of resolvent operators)**.**
>
> (i) If $\lambda,\mu \in \rho(A)$, we have $$R_\lambda - R_\mu=(\mu-\lambda)R_\lambda R_\mu \quad \text{(resolvent identity)} \tag{12}$$ and $$R_\lambda R_\mu = R_\mu R_\lambda \tag{13}.$$

If it helps, here are the relevant definitions on the previous page. Also, $A$ is a closed linear operator on the real Banach space $X$, with domain $D(A)$.

> **DEFINITIONS.** (i) We say a real number $\lambda$ belongs to $\rho(A)$, the *resolvent set* of $A$, provided the operator $$\lambda I - A : D(A) \to X$$ is one-to-one and onto.
>
> (ii) If $\lambda \in \rho(A)$, the *resolvent operator* $R_\lambda : X \to X$ is defined by $$R_\lambda u := (\lambda I - A)^{-1} u.$$

What can I do to prove the first identity $$R_\lambda - R_\mu=(\mu-\lambda)R_\lambda R_\mu$$ at least? I got stuck after writing the following: $$R_\lambda - R_\mu = (\lambda I - A)^{-1} - (\mu I - A)^{-1}$$ and $$(\mu - \lambda) R_\lambda R_\mu = (\mu - \lambda) (\lambda I - A)^{-1} (\mu I - A)^{-1}$$
Perhaps the second identity requires similar justification, so I can try to do that on my own after getting help with the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition,

$$R_{\lambda} (\lambda-A)= (\lambda-A) R_{\lambda} = \text{id}.$$

Consequently,

$$\begin{align*} R_{\lambda}-R_{\mu} &= R_{\lambda} (\mu-A) R_{\mu} - R_{\lambda}(\lambda-A) R_{\mu} \\ &= R_{\lambda} ((\mu-A)-(\lambda-A)) R_{\mu}. \end{align*}$$

This proves (12). In order to show (13)  use (12). (Hint: What happens if we switch $\lambda \leftrightarrow \mu$ in (12)?)

Comment: @dragon For any bijective operator $B: D(B) \to X$ it holds that $$B B^{-1} = B^{-1} B = \text{id}.$$ This follows from the very definition of $B^{-1}$ being the inverse of $B$.

Comment: To derive (13), I use (12) as you suggest. I got $R_\lambda R_\mu = \frac 1{\mu-\lambda}(R_\lambda - R_\mu)$. Now, when I interchange the roles of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in (12), I obtain $$R_\mu R_\lambda = \frac 1{\lambda - \mu}(R_\mu - R_\lambda) = -\frac 1{\mu - \lambda}(R_\mu - R_\lambda) = \frac 1{\mu - \lambda}(R_\lambda - R_\mu).$$ Thus, I can equate the two expressions together and thereby prove (13).

Comment: @dragon Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For the first inequality, look at
$$
(\lambda I - A)(R_{\lambda}-R_{\mu})(\mu I-A)
$$
on $D(A)$.